# PhoneGap Build API for Node.js - Unable to load a custom build

Tags: phonegap-build

I am trying to upload a zip file containing my App into PhoneGap Build by using the API with Node.js but it doesn't work, it does if I upload the file manually from the website.

After a successfully authentication with this piece of code:

```
pgBuild.auth({ token: phonegapBuildToken }, authenticationResponse);
```

in my callback I do the following:

```
function authenticationResponse(e, api){

     unlockAndroidKeyMethod(api);
     unlockiOSKeyMethod(api);

     var options = {
        form: {
           data: {
              platforms: ['android', 'ios']
           },
           file: './www/xxx.zip'
         }
     };

     api.post(phonegapEndpoint + '/build', options, function(ee, data) {
         console.log('## BUILD IN PROGRESS...');
         console.log(ee);
         console.log(data);
         //waitingForPendingBuild(api);
    });
}
```

inside the option I am pointing to the file I want to load

```
file: './www/xxx.zip'
```

the problem is that whatever I put there it doesn't get picked up, what PhoneGap Build builds is the file always the file loaded through the website.

Can I get some help, please? :)

Thanks

PS: I get no error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solved this problem - it was a problem on how I create the zip file apparently...PhoneGap Build API don't like zip files done with gulp-zip, using archiverjs (https://archiverjs.com/docs/) solves the issue :)

Thanks